# how to hide chart linechartoption in angular type js

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

how to hide chart linechartoption in angular type js.
i want to hide specified option at the top of chart.

https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/doughnut.html

i'm tired with this problem.
I wants to hide options at the top of chart (using angular).

Comment: Need more information, have you tried any code? which top option you are taking about? Do you mean labels of the charts?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the labels, you can just turn them off at the start.

In your ts file you need to use @VieChild to get a connection to your chart.

```
@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective, {static: false}) chart: BaseChartDirective;
```

Should call you chart in the html:

```
  <canvas baseChart #baseChart..
```

To turn of the label you can use this in ngAfterViewInit:

```
this.chart.chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[0].hidden = true;
```